# Mongoose find min in subdocument and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose with Node.js.I want to find and update the subdocument with the most min key value(or the oldest) for a specific vendor.

```
var VendorSchema = new Schema({
  Vendor: {type: String, Required: 'Please enter your name'},  
  r: [{
    userID:{type: ObjectId},
    name: {type: String},
    key: {type: Number},
    lastUpdated: {type: Date},
    done: {type: Number},
    statusID: {type: [{type: Number,enum: [0, 1]}],default: [1]}
  }]
});
```

**Edit 1:** Added a new element.
Suppose if I want to get the oldest r for a vendor where status is 1, get its values and update it's status to 0, how do I do that.

Comment: Presuming that you don't actually manipulate the array with a modifier such as [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/update/sort/) then surely the "oldest" is always the **first index** of the array. Therefore `{ "$set": { "r.0.name": "new name" } }` or something along those lines depending on which properties you need to actually update. See ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#arrays) in the reference

Comment: Sorry for not being precise.I have updated the question.Please suggest.